# Using OpenCV with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have been trying to use OpenCV with Qt Creator, but I had no success. I read lot of forums but none helped.

Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <qDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("lol.jpg");

    cv::namedWindow("MyImage",45);

    cv::imshow("MyImage",image);
    qDebug()<<"TEST-OCV-1";
    cv::waitKey(1000);
    return a.exec();
}
```

My `.pro` File

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = ocv1
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += F:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include
LIBS += -LF:/OpenCV/opencv/build/x64/vc12/bin \
-llibopencv_core240d \
-llibopencv_highgui240d \
-llibopencv_imgproc240d \
-llibopencv_features2d240d \
-llibopencv_calib3d240d \
```

I have also tried including the libs like

```
LIBS += -LF:/OpenCV/opencv/build/x64/vc12/lib \
-lopencv_core249 \
-lopencv_highgui249 \
-lopencv_imgproc249 \
-lopencv_features2d249 \
-lopencv_calib3d249 \
```

And

```
LIBS += -LF:/OpenCV/opencv/build/x64/vc12/lib \
-lopencv_core249 \
-lopencv_highgui249 \
-lopencv_imgproc249 \
-lopencv_features2d249 \
-lopencv_calib3d249 \
```

But I keep getting this error, though a command prompt starts it just as the text press enter to exit.

```
Starting C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-ocv1-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\debug\ocv1.exe...
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-ocv1-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\debug\ocv1.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

Comment: Most probably you did not provide the opencv dlls. 2 options : Copy the required opencv dlls to your executable folder or put the opencv dll folder into the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Did that but still getting
Starting C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-ocv1-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\debug\ocv1.exe...
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-ocv1-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\debug\ocv1.exe exited with code -1073741515

Comment: In order to be sure that dlls are found, run your application by double clicking on it, not from Qt Creator. It will first ask for Qt dlls. Copy them to your executable folder. When you copy all Qt dlls, it you should not get any errors regarding to OpenCV dlls.

Comment: Well the exe runs but the qtcreator still gives the error.